# What does c refer to in AR(p) and MA(q) model mathematical definitions?

Tags: arima, autoregressive, intercept, moving-average

What exactly does c represent in these formulas defining AR(p) and MA(q) models?

MA(q):

[image]

(https://otexts.com/fpp2/MA.html)

AR(p):

[image]

https://otexts.com/fpp2/AR.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$c$ is an [intercept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-intercept), like the analogous parameter in Ordinary Least Squares regression. Note how the example time series at your links oscillate around $c=20$. Without this intercept, they would oscillate around zero. The `auto.arima()` function in the `forecast` package will assume you want to fit a model with such an intercept if you don't tell it otherwise (other ARIMA fitting methods may not assume this, be careful).